# Is possible to create a script that disallows the command rm in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, rm

Is possible to create a script that disallows the command rm in linux ?

Comment: You mean for a specific user?

Comment: could be for sudo also

Comment: forbidding rm command might be possible, however user can run ruby script which calls `File.unlink()`, and various other method for deleting file.
I think this is [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). what the actual problem are you facing ?

Comment: im looking for a way to make linux as secure as mac in that sense of protecting the system files from a rm all I really need is to avoid in any case a rm on the system files would encrypt the files avoid that ?

Comment: Well, mac uses a different approach for that, as it has the possibility (inherited from its BSD  origin) of marking files as immutable, and neither root has access to modify them (only by unmarking them again).  This doesn't make mac more secure than linux, anyway.  Only if you don't know the reason it's more secure.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own shell that mimics the command-line and sends all normal input to the actual command-line except for rm commands.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's a more elegant solution though.

Comment: Actually no. As far I can see, this is the only way - and you must be VERY restrictive in what you allow the user to do in this shell. No access to a compiler, for instance. Of course no access to other shells or programs which can implicitly execute commands. In fact, it would be a shell where you offer just a very limited amount of features. You *can* allow sudo as long as you make sure that the commands executed via sudo don't violate these security restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

you could add a alias in your `.bashrc`

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

this will force you to confirm each time you rm a file unless you run `rm -f`

and if you alias like this:

```
alias rm='echo "command rm is forbidden"'
```

this will forbid the rm command

Note that alias will only prevent you from a miss-typing. not a system security fasten, if you really want user to have root privilege to run rm command:

```
$which rm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 64424 Jan 20 22:46 /bin/rm
$sudo chomd 744 /bin/rm
```

that will force the user to be root to run `rm` command.

Technically you can't disable **root** to delete files on your system, because root can do anything, but if user gain the privilege through `sudo`(which is not the real user **root** but gain  privilege temporarily) there are ways to disable specific command from running even by sudo through the sudo config file [check this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500679/block-a-command-from-sudo-user)

Comment: you mean you want to forbid user to run `rm` even with a `sudo`(which will gain a root privilege) ?

Comment: yes exactly or at least put an alias on the command also for sudo

Comment: in that case, you should follow the post I give to restrict commands via `sudo` config fle.

Answer (score 0):

for a specific user you can do like this

Lshell is configured via an INI file. By default, it holds a whitelist of allowed commands, but it can be easily configured to prohibit user from using a specific command.

This configuration (default conf /etc/lshell.conf) prohibits user foo from using mkdir:

```
 [foo]
 allowed = 'all' - ['mkdir', 'bash', 'sh', 'csh', 'dash', 'env']
```